# SQL Max() question

Tags: sqlite

Right now I'm doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE location_id = 7 AND date(date) <= date('now', 'localtime') ORDER BY date,revision LIMIT 1
```

This gives me the most recent message, with the highest revision #.

How can retrieve all of the most recent messages?  If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE date(date) <= date('now', 'localtime') ORDER BY date,revision
```

I still get messages with lower revision numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query that finds the most recent revision per location:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM messages m1
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages m2 
  ON (m1.location_id = m2.location_id AND m1.revision < m2.revision)
WHERE m2.location_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY date, revision;
```

Comment: Hey Bill,

I'm actually trying to find the most recent comment (ie, highest revision number, most recent date) per location_id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages m1
WHERE date(date) <= date('now', 'localtime') 
  and revision = (select max(revision) from messages m2 where date(m2.date) = date(m1.date))
  and location_id = 7
ORDER BY date,revision
```